# Unable to launch Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm unable to launch the Jupyter on Anaconda. I'm using windows, how can I get rid of this error? The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 64, in 
raise ImportError(_("The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have %s") % tornado.version)
ImportError: The Jupyter Notebook requires tornado >= 5.0, but you have 4.5.3
```

Comment: The error explains what the problem is that you're encountering.  You'll need to upgrade your version of tornado to at least v5.0.

Comment: How can I upgrade to version 5.0? is it possible with Anaconda Prompt Powershell?

Comment: [Perhaps this will help you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/update-module?view=powershell-7.1) (I found this with Google; I don't use Windows).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can probably remove it off your system then put it back on with for python

```
sudo apt-get remove python-tornado
sudo pip install tornado
```

similarly you could run it for python 3 if neccesary

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-tornado
sudo pip3 install -U tornado
```

or you could try the following to upgrade tornado

```
sudo pip install tornado --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

you said :

> I'm unable to launch the Jupyter on Anaconda.

you can update it from Anaconda.Navigator

1. go to Anacondas' Environments
2. search about tornado
3. remove it
   4.you will find your `tornado 4.5.3`

[image]

5. click on the check then choose
6. make for a specific version --> 6.1
7. go to Anacondas' home page then ran jupyter [install -> launch ]
   done

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling tornado with: (pip uninstall  tornado)
for some reason after deleting my tornado 4.5.3 it automatically updated to Version 6. and started working perfectly fine, I don't know the exact reason, possibly a missing dependency was auto installed I guess. whatever it is, this worked for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeyod.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to launch Jupyter due to the same error that was present.

Initially I tried upgrading the specific version of tornado, however, anaconda stated that upgrading to tornado 5.0 is incompatible with the version of python.

Running the `conda update --force conda` command in anaconda prompt managed to resolve the problem.

Note: this solution may no longer work in the future as the force flag is due to be removed.